# How to make Normal div on top of absolute if they are children of relative?

Tags: css, layout, html, position

So I have a wrapper div with relative position,
to the bottom of it there is another absolute div which should be on top of it,
another child of the relative div wrapper is the actual content div, which does not have position set.
Now what happens is that the absolute div gets on top the content.
I can't use z index because the content div has no position...
Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Will be better if you setup a jsfiddle demo.

Comment: well the question is straight-forward I suppose;

Comment: Ok, where should the absolute div actually be ?

Comment: bottom of wrapper ? outside wrapper but below it ?

Comment: You can use z-index if you set its position to relative; you don't need to actually set coordinates.

Comment: the absolute div has a bottom:0 of the wrapper...

Comment: I've just had this idea too Gary :) Give me a sec and I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z-index can be applied to any element with a [relative, absolute or fixed position](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index).

Set the div's position to relative (you don't have to set top or left) and then set the z-index.